# how to filter json array using another json array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an response as a json array with lots of records but i want to filter that json array by using another json array.

my json response

http://prntscr.com/lvxwob

and my filter json array be like

```
"filterParams" : [ 
        {
            "param" : "actualSum",
            "value" : "95",
            "type" : "text",
            "comparision" : "isEqual"
        }, 
        {
            "param" : "wbsSort",
            "value" : "6",
            "type" : "text",
            "comparision" : "isEqual"
        }
    ],
```

so how can i filter my response using javascript or node js anything. i want to get filtered data like match param with reponse param and its value.

e.g. 
if there is match value of actualSum with 95 and wbsSort's value equal to 6 then  it will return true other wise false.

Comment: Do you want to return whether there is some results (`true` or `false`)  as you said or really filtering down the results to the specified parameters ?

Comment: please add your try as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the items in the result array where the item matches [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) parameter in `filterParams`. If you only want to check if at least one match exists replace `.filter` with [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

e.g.

```
var matches = results.filter(item =>
  filterParams.every(paramItem =>
    item[paramItem.param] === paramItem.value));
```

I've limited it to equals comparison but you can expand the comparison using a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) based on the other comparison types you have.

Comment: thank you, but when i log it on my console it will return true as per my filter but final data result array length is 0 why it has happening?

Comment: Do you mean the `matches` array? Could it be that it is being modified elsewhere?

Comment: yes i am asking about matches array. no it is not modified elsewhere

Comment: It's hard to say what is happening without seeing more code. Might be suited for a new question?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without having to hardcode every check would be to create a compare function using the `filterParams`. So you would do something like this, where `compareFunction` creates a new function using `filterParams` to initialize the variables to check and returns whether the current item has these values. So for any further check you want to do, you will only have to add it to filterParams. Hope this helps.

```js
const filterParams = [{
        "param" : "actualSum",
        "value" : "95",
        "type" : "text",
        "comparison" : "isEqual"
    }, {
        "param" : "wbsSort",
        "value" : "6",
        "type" : "text",
        "comparison" : "isEqual"
    }];

const data = [{ actualSum: 95, wbsSort: 6 }, { actualSum: 95, wbsSort: 10 }];

const operators = {
    'isEqual': '==='
};

const compareFunction = (params) =>
    (item) => new Function(
        params.reduce((acc, { param, value }) => `${acc} const ${param} = ${value};`, '') +
        params.reduce((acc, { param, value, comparison }, i) => `${acc} ${param} ${operators[comparison]} ${item[param]} ${i !== params.length - 1 ? '&&' : ';'}`, 'return ')
    )();

const filteredData = data.filter(compareFunction(filterParams));

console.log(filteredData);
```